# Seeking data for Mapping Pubs in London?

Tags: data, united-kingdom

I want to make a map showing pubs in London but don't know how to go about getting the data. I have looked on digimap and downloaded a few things but none seem to be right. any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange! Maybe you ask your question better here: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Take the tour here:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour  As Iris suggested, opendata may be a better place for this question.

Comment: contact http://www.pub-explorer.com/contacts.htm for permission to use view-source:http://www.pub-explorer.com/map.htm?county=&selected_county=&location=london&last_location=&submit=Show+Pubs#map (Can take time to load the map and all the pubs in London.)

Answer (score 3):

Using **OpenStreetMap** data http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API (as London is very well mapped) no issues with license/permissons

- goto: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/dii (the query will run automatically)

*except the processing is large (continue option) as goes over 2mb in the web browser.

- Export as GeoJSON
- Open QGIS load the GeoJSON file and you should have

[image]

Comment: You may notice there seems to be no pubs in the City Of London area. Not because bankers are all sober, teetotal chaps and chapesses, but because the spatial query for "London" doesn't include "The City". Using "Greater London" works a bit better.

Comment: greater london script http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/div click run is slightly larger (browser will complain - just continue) 2304 points vs 2190 [just 'london'] @Spacedman

Comment: Nice. Someone owes you a pint :)

Comment: @Spacedman on the tab https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye_Olde_Cheshire_Cheese >rebuilt< in 1667

Comment: There's also QuickOSM, a QGIS plugin - this saves you the additional  GeoJSON export step in overpass turbo,

Comment: @Mapperz: " no issues with license/permissons " - that's not entirely correct. The data is of course copyrighted under the ODbL. See http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright for details.

Answer (score 1):

Ujaval Ghandi has a nice tutorial in QGIS on exactly how to do that here:

http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/downloading_osm_data.html

Comment: Note that you will download pretty much all data for London using this approach (not only pubs) and filter them later on in QGIS. imho not a very efficent approach, given that you can filter pubs via Overpass API and/or QuickOSM (QGIS plugin).

Answer (score 0):

The Points of Interest layer on [EDINA Digimap](http://digimap.edina.ac.uk/datadownload/osdownload) has pub locations.

Comment: how do I go about getting this? I'm at uni so have access to digimap data but when I tried to download it was as .csv file? so I couldn't work out how to input this onto ArcGIS?

Comment: The csv file has British National Grid easting and northing coordinates. You can add the csv to ArcMap, then right click on the layer in the Table of Contents and select Display XY Data.

Comment: i tried this but I cant select any x data or y data? any idea what I'm doing wrong? :(

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 0):

The Points of Interest data form Digimap has the pub locations but there are some quirks when it comes to using it. It is a .csv file but the columns are not separated by commas but by the pipe symbol: | This is done because there are sometimes commas in the text fields.  ArcGIS needs a schema.ini file in the same folder as the .csv file to tell it that it needs to use pipes and not commas to separate the columns.

Digimap has provided a help page which explains what you need to create to use the PoI data in ArcGIS:

http://digimap.edina.ac.uk/webhelp/digimapgis/index.htm#arcgis/standard_arcgis_functions/importing_text_files_arcgis.htm